# Force client to talk to a different AWS region

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront

If I'm in the northeast US and trying to talk to a site on AWS, behind CloudFront, I'm generally getting routed to servers in us-east. For a particular hostname (say, myfico.com), is there any way to force e.g. curl to talk with servers in a different region, presumably by routing my traffic to a different CloudFront edge server?

Since amazon publishes the [IP ranges of all their edge servers](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json), I suspect it might be possible to do something like overriding some of my DNS records and forcing it to use an IP prefix from a different region. IT might also be possible to do a more general location spoofing by modifying the edns-client-subnet that's passed along in the DNS request, but I think this might not be possible.

Comment: Your request seems a bit suspicious, as it sounds like this is not your site.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

AWS regions are not really related to the CloudFront CDN. Generally speaking AWS region is the region where the server is physically located while the CDN offers a termination point to the client so that it can get a reply from the server quickly. You can possibly hit a CDN node in West US but the request may still be routed to us-east if the website is configured that way.